# Using Different Java Code in a Project (How to reach variables)

Tags: java, methods

I wrote a simple drawing program, and for to create a menu, I used this source, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/MenuLookDemoProject/src/components/MenuLookDemo.java

Therefore in my program to show the menus, I only added these lines:

```
    MenuDemo demo = new MenuDemo();
    frame.setJMenuBar(demo.createMenuBar());
```

When I started the program, menu successfully works, but on the other hand, for example, when I click sth on menu, in method "actionPerformed" I want to change my program's boolean variable. But "actionPerformed" is exist in "MenuLookDemo.java", therefore I cannot reach the variables.

Can you suggest a solution please ?

Thanks

Comment: You should really start reading about Object-Oriented design. This is a OO-101-level question.

Comment: Is it not OK to ask OO-101 level questions here? I thought it was perfectly OK to ask this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can rewrite the class `MenuDemo` and pass your Object to `MenuDemo` to access your variable.

```
class MenuDemo{
  YourType obj;
  MenuDemo(YourType obj){
    this.obj = obj;
  }
  // Now you can access elements of obj
}
```

Comment: Pikaurd is right -- MenuDemo needs some way to send information to your program (really -- your object, represented in his sample as 'obj').

Comment: I tried this one, but the main problem is, I want some variables to be effected when "actionPerformed" event flagged. I added arguments to the MenuDemo, but I cant send this object to "actionPerformed" method, therefore I cant reach that variable

Comment: Where is your actionPerformed? Can your paste your project structure here? I thought actionPerformed in MemoDemo, so the menu element could handle actions its received.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what Pikaurd has above, do this:

```
public class MyType {
  int x;
  public void doTheNeedful() {
    x = 5;
  }
}
```

Then make sure `MenuDemo` contains a field `obj` of class `MyType`.  Inside `actionPerformed()`, call `obj.doTheNeedful()`.

I'm deliberately not just giving you the code on this; the sentence above should be enough for you to figure it out.